# Name collision of classes not exposed in static libraries interface (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries

I have two static libraries (`a.lib` and `b.lib`)
internally, library `a` has class `Foo`, but it is not exposed in any publicly available includes. Library `b.lib` also has class `Foo` and it is also not exposed in interface. Those classes are in the same namespace and have the same constructor signature.

When I am debugging or running executable (which is using both libraries) I see that wrong class from `lib a` instead of `lib b` is created.
Trying to understand how is this happening. Is it a linker problem? (i.e. class names are the same and linker is inserting whatever it finds first)

Comment: There is no such thing as a class internal to a static library (the story is different with DLLs). The fact that a name is not mentioned in a header doesn't mean anything. Your program violates One Definition Rule by containing two non-identical definitions of the same class.

Comment: use namespaces. Even ignoring the problem you describe I wonder how you manage to not get confused with two classes sharing the same name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static libraries are seldom more than archives of object files. When linking with a static library it's the same as linking with the separate object files. And an object file is basically a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). And because of [the One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) you can't have two different classes in different translation units with the same name, as that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

If you want to have "private" classes inside a library, use *namespaces* and define the "private" classes inside the (uniquely named) namespace.

Comment: Don't try to make up "unique" namespaces on your own. Use anonymous namespaces. They, and everything in them has internal linkage. It's as though the compiler itself generated a unique namespace for you.

Comment: @StoryTeller While anonymous namespaces are best, they only work inside a single translation unit. For a library internal data-structures may need to be shared between multiple translation units, and then anonymous namespaces won't work.

Comment: But that's the thing. The OP supposedly has two classes in the same namespace form different libraries. I won't be surprised if the namesapce may just be `PRIVATE`, or something generic like that that's meant to "protect" the class definition. Anyway, this is another point in favor of modules (hopefully in C++2a).